# Table statistic descriptive with two PANEL

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

I'm trying to separate my variables into two different panels (panel A and Pabel B).

Here my desired output :

[image]

My code :

```
   \documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
 \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{booktabs} % For better looking tables
 \usepackage{natbib}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{enumerate}
  \usepackage{enumitem}                 
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage{empheq}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{amssymb}
   \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
     \usepackage{array}
     \usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
      \usepackage{slashed}
       \usepackage[english]{babel}
       \usepackage[figurename=Fig.]{caption}
        \usepackage{tabulary}
         \usepackage{tabularx}
          \usepackage{varioref}
           \usepackage{multirow}

            \begin{document}

           \newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\scriptsize #1}}
        \newcolumntype{P}{>{\raggedright\scriptsize}p{4.5cm}}
        \newcolumntype{R}{*{5}{>{\scriptsize}c}}

     \begin{table}[H]
        \caption{Descriptive statistics}
      \label{tab:tab_Descriptive statistics}
      \begin{center}
     \begin{tabular}{@{}P@{\kern-30pt}R@{}}\toprule 
      \texttt{variables} 
     & \mc{No of observations}              
     &\mc{Mean}
     &\mc{Standard Deviation}
    &\mc{Minimum}&\mc{Maximum}\\[-2pt]
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-5} \cmidrule(lr) 
    {6-6}
   Recession   &  17,460  & 6.626403  &  13.00181 & 0 &100\\ 
   Conspiracy Theory  &  17,460  & 5.200745  &  11.1865  &0  & 100 \\ 
  Stock Market Crash \newline & 17,460 &  2.293414         & 7.142563         & 0  &100\\[-8pt]
    Survivalism      &17,460&    1.903379&    6.063206 &0 &100\\
    covid confirmed cases & 3,276& 605.0104& 6179.405&0&80151\\
    covid death         &  3,276 & 17.40781 &191.2796 & 0 &2945\\
   covid recovered &3,276&158.1761&2133.75&0 &47404\\
  \bottomrule %
  \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
 \end{table}

 \end{document}
```

My output :

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of `P@{\kern-30pt}`? Wouldn't a simple `l` type column be sufficient?

Comment: @leandriis hi my friend it is good to hear from you, actually, I found the sample table here from others suggestions but I couldn't find a way to modify it as desired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see no reason for using `\scriptsize` in this table. I would, though, shorten some of the column headers.

I would also (a) align the numbers on their (implicit or explicit) decimal markers, with the help of the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type, and (b) round the numbers to 2 decimal digits. After all, are readers really better off being told that some variable is equal to `6.626403`, or would they be better served with `6.63`? The `S` column type allows automatic rounding.

Off-topic: Don't load both `enumerate` and `enumitem`; I would load just the latter package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
 \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{booktabs} % For better looking tables
 \usepackage{natbib}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{enumitem}                 
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage[figurename=Fig.,skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}

 \usepackage{siunitx}
 \newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1,group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits=4]}
 \newcolumntype{U}[1]{S[table-format=#1,round-precision=2,round-mode=places]}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
     \caption{Descriptive statistics}
     \label{tab:tab_Descriptive statistics}
     \centering
     \begin{tabular}{@{} l T{5.0} U{3.2} U{4.2} c T{5.0} @{}}
     \toprule 
     Variables & {No of obs.} & {Mean} & {St.\ Dev.} & {Minimum} & {Maximum} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4}
    \cmidrule(lr){5-5} \cmidrule(l){6-6}
    \textbf{Panel A}\\
    Recession          & 17460  &    6.626403 & 13.00181  & 0 &   100\\  
    Conspiracy Theory  & 17460  &    5.200745 & 11.1865   & 0 &   100\\ 
    Stock Market Crash & 17460  &    2.293414 &  7.142563 & 0 &   100\\
    Survivalism        & 17460  &    1.903379 &  6.063206 & 0 &   100\\[0.5ex]
    \textbf{Panel B}\\
    Covid confirmed cases & 3276 & 605.0104   & 6179.405  & 0 & 80151\\
    Covid deaths          & 3276 &  17.40781  &  191.2796 & 0 &  2945\\
    Covid recovered       & 3276 & 158.1761   & 2133.75   & 0 & 47404\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is an email for you :-)))